# Isaiah 53:3 acquainted with חלי - grief, suffering or infirmity?

Tags: hebrew, isaiah

I noticed that in the English חלי is some times translated as grief *e.g.* KJV, ESV, NASB. The NRSV translates it as infirmity which personally I think is a better translation of חלי. The LXX likewise translates it as μαλακιαν which in turn is translated disease.

Even though of the 24 occurrences חלי is used, 4 times its translated grief or griefs, the other 20 times its sickness, disease, sick or sicknesses.

What is the best translation of חלי suffering or sickness?

> “He was despised and rejected by men, a man of sorrows and **acquainted with grief**; and as one from whom men hide their faces he was despised, and we esteemed him not.”
> ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭53:3‬ ‭

Answer (score 1):

Whatever one says about חֱלִי in Isa 53;3 one must also say about its occurrence in V4 because the two appear in parallel - V4 builds on the meaning in V3.

It is certainly true that חֱלִי most often means sickness/infirmity.  In fact, of the 24 times this word appears in the OT, 20 times it is translated sickness/affliction/disease, etc, and four times "grief".  However, in the NASB, this ration rises to 22 times vs 2 times with Isa 53:3 & 4 being the notable exceptions.

Therefore, I will allow that the probable meaning in Isa 53:3 & 4 is probably "infirmity".  That said, what does that mean?

Isa 52:13 - 53:12 is the fourth of the famous "servant songs" of Isaiah otherwise known as prophecies of Messiah.  In Isa 53:3 & 4, we learn two major things about this (then) future Messiah:

1. Messiah would know or be familiar with infirmity (V3).  The LXX has μαλακία = sickness/infirmity
2. Messiah would take or bear our infirmities (V4).  The LXX has ἁμαρτία = sin

The simplest explanation here is that the "infirmity" of humanity itself because

1. Messiah was definitely human and so understood us (Heb 4:14-16 - note V15 has ἀσθένεια = weaknesses/frailty)
2. Messiah took all our infirmities, our sinful natures, our failings (1 John 2:2)

These two texts, Isa 53:3 & 4, contain, in a very kernel, the essence of the NT Gospel.

Comment: "In fact, of the 24 times this word appears in the OT, 20 times it is translated sickness/affliction/disease, etc, and four times "grief". Can you please provide a reference?

Comment: @Bach - see https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2483.htm